# Cannot make correct line break

Tags: xetex, pdftex, line-breaking, luatex, hyphenation

I installed TexLive 2016 on a Mac, default last version install:

- XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)
- LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)

I am trying to make a book for professional printing (it has specific dimensions).

For better looking I want to use EBGaramond face. I run the following MWE through xelatex, luatex and pdflatex:

```
%+LATEX: xelatex


\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
 Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.00, Extension=.otf,
 Ligatures = TeX ,
 UprightFont = *-Regular,
 ItalicFont = *-Italic,
 BoldItalicFont = *-Italic,
 BoldItalicFeatures = {FakeBold=3},
 AutoFakeBold = 3,
]{EBGaramond12}%
\else
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\fi

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}




\usepackage[
 showframe,
 % 6/9
 paperwidth=15.24cm,
 paperheight=22.86cm,
 bindingoffset=0.625in,
 hmargin={0.0in,0.5in},
 vmargin={0.5in,0.5in},
 includeall, nomarginpar, twoside,
 ignorehead=false, ignorefoot=false, ignoremp=false,
 %%nohead,
 headsep=0.5em,
 footskip=1.2em,
]{geometry}


\makeatletter
\def\@cit#1{\og{}#1\fg{}}
\def\@@cit#1{``#1''}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cit}{\@ifstar\@@cit\@cit}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rub}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\newrobustcmd{\s}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
      {\textbf{#1}}%
      \endgroup%
}%


\newcommand{\tl}{--\xspace}
\newcommand{\sep}{\discretionary{}{}{}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

pdfLaTeX:

\rub{Lecteurs}: \cit{Les \s{r}iches \s{m}utent.} \tl \cit{Veolia:
Frérot introduit \s{Au}l\s{a}gnon.}\tl \cit{L'heu\s{r}eux
\s{n}ageur.} \tl \cit{\s{D}ites, \s{B}éranger!}

\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex]
[image: lualatex]
[image: pdflatex]

It seems the hyphen does not work correctly. From a previous question ([broken hyphen when emphasising part of the word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328279/)) I was told hyphen only work if there is no font change in the word. For some reason I need emphase some parts of the word. Using a bold face is the best way I found. I do not want to use italic.

As I cannot hyphen the `L'heureux` word I prefer the line to be broken before it. Of course I can use a `\linebreak` and the result seems to be fine. BUT if I change to book format (from a 6/9 to pocket for example), I would have a line break which would have no sense.

For the moment I manually track all overfull warnings and add a manual hyphen point (`\-`) but this is fastidious.

I also tried `\penalty-9999` without any success (`\penalty-10000` issues a line break).

Is there a way to force a linebreak only if next word generate an `Overfull \hbox`?

I also wrote a small macro (`\newcommand{\sep}{\discretionary{}{}{}}`). Sometimes it helps to break the line correctly but not always.

I prefer a XeLaTex solution for several reasons:

- LuaLaTex does not support fake bold (I know this is bad but here the result is pleasant enough)
- pdflatex generated ugly frenchquotes with the `ebgaramond` package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XeTeX (and pdfTeX) don't hyphenate words that aren't typeset in a single font.

Comment: your code seems wrong for luatex, you are only using fontspec for xetex, but you should be using it (and not inputenc) for luatex

Comment: @egreg Neither LuaLaTeX. Anyway is there a way to force a line break only if next word is out of the text body?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle even with `fontspec` in lualatex the hyphen / line break is buggy.

Comment: you could increase \emergencystretch (or use \sloppy) but that would increase white space and break before the word, not  break the word. Also `\newrobustcmd{\s}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
      {\textbf{#1}}%
      \endgroup%
}%` why all the groups, could just be `\newcommand\s{\textbf}` as `\textbf` implies a group, and then you add two more, from `{}` and `\begingroup\endgroup`

Comment: It's not buggy it is as specified that it doesn't hyphenate letter combinations that include font changes. perhaps you want `\newcommand\s[1]{\-\textbf{#1}\-}` so that hyphenation is allowed either side of the font change?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used to put text in red for better reading. I do not really care if the whole line is a bit stretched as long as the the text does not bite the margins.

Comment: use `\sloppy` then

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\sloppy` seems to be a good solution. Meanwhile is there a way to limit its scope to a few lines only?

Comment: yes \fussy puts it back or use `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}`  But I think we have a duplicate question about use of \sloppy, I'll find

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45359/discussion-between-renard-and-david-carlisle).